# debug a debug dll linked to a release executable

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2005

In visual studio how can I debug/step into calls made by an exe to a library ?
The exe is available only in release mode and calls the library which is built in debug mode 
I made a simple vs solution with just the exe and started it ..then I opened a source file from the binary and added breakpoints.. but vs doesnot activate the breakpoints saying "no symbols loaded for this file" ...obviously I am missing something here.. (if I remember correctly I used to be able to debug the calls before)

Answer (score 1):

You can debug binaries that are built in release mode with the following caveats:

1. You'll need the pdbs which were built against the release library.
2. Breakpoints will not be possible in any code which has been inlined/optimized away.
3. Depending on the architecture certain variables values will be hidden/garbage, you have to take things with a pinch of salt when debugging release binaries.

To add PDB files for the release binary, go to:

```
Debug -> Options and Settings -> Symbols
```

Comment: thanks.. but in this case I dont even have pdb files for the exe. I have the pdb files for the dll and the dll is debug.... Also I just want to add breakpoints in the source code of the dll..to see how the exe is exercising the dll functionality..

Comment: Hmm, that should work just fine, are you sure that the exe is loading the version of the library that you've just built?  If it was built on your machine the pdbs should be found automatically.

Comment: Hi @mhk , Did u solve this problem? what is the solution for attaining this ?